# I'm applying some properties in css But my properties aren't applied because of bootstrap's css property. I don't know what i should type

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, web-development-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bzBO.png)

```
.container, .container-fluid, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm, .container-xl, .container-xxl {
    --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
    --bs-gutter-y: 0;
    width: 100%;
    **padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);**
    **padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);**
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}


.container-fluid {
    padding: 3% 15%; //I'm trying to implement this.
}
```

Because of .container-fluid's property my padding aren't applied in left and right side only.
I want padding in left and right side.

I also tried applying:
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;

Nothing is working!!!

Comment: Make the selector more specific. Try duplicating the custom selector `.container-fluid.container-fluid {`

Comment: you can use !important with padding so it will overwrite

Comment: ".container-fluid.container-fluid {" THIS WORKED but I didn't get it how it became more specific. Btw Thank you @evolutionxbox

Comment: Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity. Specificity is a fundamental (in my opinion) concept in CSS.

Comment: can you tell your socialmedia handle.

Answer (score 0):

for such problem I would prefer to see html as well. From what you shared uI suggest you override the css by using its parent .container

code :

```
.container .container-fluid 
 {
   padding-left: 0px; 
   padding-right: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: I already tried this and in html I normally used bootstrap classes that's all